# Using time dependent covariates in Gamma frailty Cox model

Tags: cox-model, time-varying-covariate, frailty

I have a dataset with repeated episodes per individual, trying to determine factors associated to the outcome of interest. I am planning to use a gamma frailty Cox model to account for intra individual correlation. On the other hand I have very precisely recorded covariates (separately recorded on each day of each episode) and I would like to make the most of this.

Is there any issue with using time dependent covariates in a Gamma frailty model? And does it make sense? SAS allows me to do it, but I haven't found any research article mentioning this combination. Any hints appreciated.

Edit: An additional question would be how to evaluate model quality in this context?